# OpenLdap multiple administrators under the same DC

Tags: openldap

Im currently playing with openldap (+phpldapadmin)
Howver i dont know how to create a new adminuser for ldap.

Tried to clone the CN=admin as another name, but in that case in phpldapadmin.
I can login with that new account however i got the following error
`This base cannot be created with PLA.` in the tree view.
Sadly nor search is possible with that.

Is there any tip howto create multiple CN user under the DC=example,DC=org ?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This community is related to software development. I think your chances for fast and good answer will be better if you ask your question at https://serverfault.com/

Comment: I am facing the same issue.
Have you found a solution @TurboGoat97?
Thanks